# How to avoid popup cmd?

Tags: python, module

I am writing a program which has to call another program. So I've done some research and found the os module. The problem with this solution is that the cmd always pops up. How can I avoid this?

So far I used the command like this: `os.system("something.py")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably found in the `subprocess` module.

Now there is not really any detail as to what you are trying to do when `something.py` runs, so lets say we have a file called `test.py` that creates a new file and writes something:

**test.py**

```
t = r"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\test.txt"

with open(t, 'w') as f:
    f.write("This worked!")
```

So in whatever program we want to run `test.py`, we would have the following:

```
import subprocess
f = r"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\test.py"
subprocess.run(f, shell=True) # shell=True since this is really an arg
```

And the program will execute without opening a terminal. See here:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> f = r"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\test.py"
>>> subprocess.run(f, shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args='C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\test.py', returncode=0)
```

Comment: On Python 3, I believe it should be `subprocess.call(f, shell=True)`.

Comment: @BillBell Actually, the `call()` method is the old API as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api)

Comment: Good you should mention that then.